# Showing that a sequence converges/diverges

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

[image]

I've managed to prove that (a) converges to 0 and (d) diverges.
However I am stuck on (b) and (c).

For (b), I assumed that it converges to $\dfrac{3}{2}$

Then did $|a_n -L|$and got to

$$\left|\dfrac{2n^2 \sin(n) + 300n +9}{4n^3 - 200n -6}\right|$$

now I'm stuck.

For (c), I assumed it converges to $L$
And then taking $\epsilon = 1$,

$$\frac{n+100^{23}}{\sqrt2 n - 10^{23}} < (L+1)^{\frac{1}{10^{\frac{1}{23}}}}$$

I guess I have to rearrange this and show that n is bounded above and hence show contradiction. But I don't know how.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For $b$, use triangle inequlity and $sin(n)<1$.

Comment: For $c$, study instead the sequence $b_n  = a_n^{10^{-23}}$. $a_n$ converges if and only if $b_n$ converges.

Comment: Part c) makes for a tough looking but easy question. The exponent $10^{23}$ is a fixed positive integer and can be safely put as one symbol $a$. Same for $100^{23} = b$. Then the base is $(n + b)/(\sqrt{2}n - a) = (1 + b/n)/(\sqrt{2} - a/n)$ which tends to $1/\sqrt{2}$. Raise it to power $a$. Don't get intimidated by large numbers.

Answer (score 3):

For (b) write

$$\frac{3n^3+n^2\sin n}{2n^3-100n-3}=\frac{3+\frac{\sin n}{n}}{2-\frac{100}{n^2}-\frac{3}{n^3}}$$
and pass to limit knowing that $\sin n$ is bounded.

Use the same method for (c)

Answer (score 0):

For (c), use that for $n$ large enough, $n+100^{23}\leqslant 1.1\cdot n$ and $\sqrt2n-10^{23}\geqslant1.2\cdot n$ (*how large $n$ should be?*) hence $a_n\leqslant a^{10^{23}}$ for $n$ large enough, with $a=\frac{1.1}{1.2}$. Can you conclude?

For (b), $a_n=\frac{3+b_n}{2-c_n}$ with $b_n=\frac{\sin n}n$ and $c_n=\frac{100}{n^2}+\frac3{n^3}$. Surely you see what happens to $b_n$ and $c_n$ when $n$ goes to infinity. Can you conclude?